# How to compare E elements

Tags: java, comparable

So what I am trying to do is compare the nodes of a list. Most of the related questions all over the internet that provides answers for this is to implement the comparable interface.

```
//This is a nested class
private static class Node<E> implements Comparable<Node<E>> {
    private E element;

    ......
    ......

    public int compareTo(Node<E> o) {
       return element >= o.element ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is it throws a compiler error `bad operand types for binary '>=' first type: E; second type: E`. I can't even use something like this: `return element.compareTo(o.element);` because `compareTo` is not defined.

What can I do to fix this? Most of the solutions for problem like this all over the net doesn't work for me... Please Help. Thanks....

Comment: I'd say that for `Node<E>` to implement `Comparable`, `E` itself should implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare it as `class Node<E extends Comparable<E>>`, so that `E` has its own `compareTo` method:

```java
private static class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<Node<E>> {
    private E element;

    public int compareTo(Node<E> o) {
       return element.compareTo(o.element);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this. It throws an error `type argument E is not within bounds of type variable E`

Comment: @robert What you tried is probably something else. This should indeed work.

Comment: It works for me. If you have some other code that uses `E` from a different class (maybe the outer class) then that `E` must `extends Comparable<E>` too. That is, the error is in the code *using* the `Node` class, not in the `Node` class itself.

Comment: @ernest_k I swear, I copied exactly this code. It doesn't work for me..

Comment: Well, edit the question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the error you're talking about, and show the full error message. This code doesn't produce an error by itself.

Comment: @ernest_k it just throws compiler error `type argument E is not within bounds of type variable` Why is that?

Comment: `type argument E` is not the same `E` as `type variable E`. You must have declared a different type variable name `E` somewhere else in your code, and you didn't say it is comparable.

Comment: @kaya3 when I tried this code it throws compiler error `type argument E is not within bounds of type variable` why is that?

Comment: @robert I just explained why. If the fix I suggested above doesn't work for you, you need to edit the question as I said.

Comment: @robert that error means that the problem is where you use the `Node` class. What you use between the `<>` after `Node` **must** be a type that implements `Comparable`

Comment: @kaya3 the error points to the declaration of `private Node<E> variable` inside the enclosing class of the nested class node,

Comment: Well, then the error is in code you didn't include in the question, isn't it? Change the declaration of the outer class the way I said to above.